# Algorithm for the maximal isotropic subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, quadratic-forms, computational-algebra

Does anyone know of any algorithms that exist which can explicitly compute a maximal isotropic subspace of a diagonal quadratic form over the rationals? I have been searching through the literature, but have been unable to find one. If so, could someone provide a reference for me? And if it is in fact quite trivial to do, would anyone be able to provide a quick summary? Thank you very much!

Comment: The first step to making a computer solve a problem for you is understanding how to solve a problem yourself. How comfortable are you with doing this yourself (in a reasonably-sized example)?

Comment: Not particularly comfortable sadly. I can do it quite easily if something is in hyperbolic form, but if not then I struggle. I know from the Witt decomposition that in theory I *can* rewrite any quadratic form as the sum of hyperbolic, radical and anisotropic parts, but I’ve not had too much success with actually implementing this.